# How to read csv files stored on adls path without downloading it locally

Tags: azure, file, apache-nifi, putty, data-ingestion

Command to find file is as below :
hdfs dfs -ls {adls file location path}

command to read listed file

Comment: to read file = download it. i can't understand your question...

Answer (score 0):

you can read a file from hdfs like below. [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hdfs-commands/) is a good tutorial.

```
  hdfs dfs -cat <path>
```